# Is there something broken with IE7 and MyOpenID?

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, login

I can login to StackOverflow but not Meta, and vice versa.

I've cleared all my cookies etc but absolutely no joy and I've associated all my accounts (didn't know if that had anything to do with it).

I did have a hunt around meta.stackoverflow to see if there were similar problems.

I'm running IE7 on Vista Ultimate. This problem also happens on my other machine running Windows 2008 Standard SP1 and IE7.

Comment: workaround in place. pretty vicious bug https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/webauth-info/2009-January/000470.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm running IE7

Ah! There's the problem. It's a known issue with how IE7 and IE8 handle cookies.

#### See: [I Can’t Log In With My OpenID — Troubleshooting Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips)

Comment: WOOOOOT WOOOOOT Troll alert! Flamebait identified! You are on the ignore list buddy!

Comment: It's an IE7/IE8 issue. I was hoping to find a better link, as i know it's been discussed before... but this is the best i can do for now.

Comment: Thought I did see that somewhere but couldn't find it again.

Comment: *shog heaves sigh of relief after successfully covering up his blatant IE bigotry*

Comment: No you didn't, I saw that, if only for a few moments :)

Comment: @Shog9: I totally saw it! Get ready for the Shog9 tag and subsequent posts!