# "Copy Profile From Stack Overflow" didn't copy alternate OpenID

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, superuser, profile-sync

I created a Super User account and copied my profile from Stack Overflow to it. Everything seemed to copy fine except for my Alt OpenID. Is this a known issue, or has anyone else noticed it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't copy OpenIDs -- just the "soft" profile fields (pretty much everything else).

However, there is now a "Copy {Site} login credentials to all Stack Exchange accounts" button on the **account tab** of your user page now:

[image]

Comment: This makes changing OpenID accounts a bit hard. Like due to [the current myOpenID's (security) issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88451/lost-my-openid-account/88456#88456), people might want to change the provider for all their accounts.

(Of course, one might use [OpenID delegation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips/63119#63119) to change it in only one place. Even then: for those who want to start using that, going in to all accounts to change it is just a bit cumbersome.)

Comment: Its a pain in the backside indeed. Now today google profiles open id provider seems to be down and I can't use any (other than SO) sites. Any reasons why "We don't copy OpenIDs"? Why do you copy anything else then? This is only misleading, because I was sure the profiles were simply cloned.

Comment: @grz did you read the above post? click "copy login credentials"

Comment: @Jeff, yes, this did fix the problem, thanks. However it didn't give me back the time I have wasted wandering wtf went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect, especially since the google open id accounts are different, that this is the intended behavior.

Comment: It makes sense when a Google OpenID is detected, but I would expect others to transfer fine.

Comment: @Ryan right, the others likely could be transfered fine, I'm just guessing that because of the google issue, they choose not to implement that. Merely a guess, at some point someone on the team will likely come by and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this too. But as my alternate is my Google OpenID and with the problems that Jeff & co had with these in the past I didn't pay it much attention.