# Username missing from Launchpad OpenID - replaced with user{number}

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, openid

Frustration!!

I have liked Stack Overflow, because I could have used my OpenID from Launchpad - and that is because I hate registering deeply.

And everything was fine, until I realize today that I have become **user277826** now, instead of sd-aau as I was up to yesterday :(

Funny enough, I just had to log in here (Meta) for the first time; when I logged in, it recognized the user name and wrote it on the intermediate page - and once I am logged in, now I've become **user151249** on Meta :( :(

What is this, and why is it happening?

Comment: I think this is a bug. I had the correct username nhnb for month. But starting this morning I am a usernumber on some stack exchange sites. I am not sure if that is really related to the global authentication mechanism.  There were some changes to the openid handling code recently (myopenid for example does not ask for a username locally anymore). Without knowing anything about the internals, i blame that.

Comment: related: [My profile just went blank?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64439/my-profile-just-went-blank)

Comment: I am having this problem over on Super user too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are no longer inferring usernames from openids.

If you want a username you must set one.

This is by design and will remain this way from this point onward.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because of the [new global authentication mechanism](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/). But you should be able to change your name by clicking on it, then choosing `edit`. Note you can change your name only once every 30 days per site (put you can use the accounts tab to copy your profile to all SE sites).

Comment: Thank you, Tobias for the answer - it's good to know that it's a new site-wide change (as opposed to suspecting something wrong happened, say, in my browser, which would have somehow sent a command to change the username). Still, I think it was **very** convenient to have the username pulled from Launchpad's OpenID - I simply didn't have to worry what I was going to be called :) Cheers!

Comment: Ok, what I did: clicked on my user link in Stack Overflow, changed my username, then clicked on the Account tab, then "Copy Stack Overflow profile to related accounts" - in the account tab, still the user{number} names will be present; but here on meta the username changed. Hope that was it with fiddling with user profiles. Another relevant link may be ["Copy Profile From Stack Overflow" didn't copy alternate OpenID - Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/copy-profile-from-stack-overflow-didnt-copy-alternate-openid)

Comment: @sdaau: I don't know much about OpenID, but maybe you could [feature-request] the automated username pulling. (Remember to mention the word "optionally" however, otherwise it might end up down-voted to oblivion...)

Comment: Global login has no effect upon user profiles.