# My profile just went blank?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Signing on today, I was showing up as "user351327" on SO and "user46143" on serverfault. Looking at my profile, every field was blank.

I'm not sure if any of the fields besides display name used to have a value.

Comment: possibly related: [Username missing from Launchpad OpenID - replaced with user{number}](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64433/username-missing-from-launchpad-openid-replaced-with-usernumber), probably this is a side-effect from the [new global authentication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/).

Comment: I can confirm this problem (openids: nhnb.de, nhnb.myopenid.com)

Comment: @user137430 / @nhnb.de: that's odd, I use myopenid, too. But maybe because I edited my username here before (in fact, I signed up on myopenID for SOFU) I'm not affected

Comment: same problem here.. as you can see! I don't know about other things blanking though.  my questions and activity and so on are still there. I'm not bothered about name being blank.. and likewise. I don't know if it ever had a value.

Comment: @user148605: you can solve this problem following [these instructions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64433/username-missing-from-launchpad-openid-replaced-with-usernumber/64434#64434). It shouldn't happen again then, but whatever the original source of your username was, will apparently be no longer used

Comment: @Jeff Atwodd - LOL, why is this status "completed"?  Completed that we are not going to do anything more about it? -- Completed implies that the bug was fixed.  But your answer says that it is by design.  Was there a change to make this not happen any more or was it "by design" that this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are no longer inferring usernames from openids.

If you want a username you must set one.

This is by design and will remain this way from this point onward.

Comment: Um... I may be blasted for this, but.... why?  It was easier on us to just infer it and transfer all the demographics from other accounts.  Not that it is a huge inconvenience for me to go fill it in again on my super user account, but... why make me do it?

Comment: I'm also interested (out of curiosity) in knowing the why of this change.

Comment: No comment?....

Comment: @Vaccano: Search for "2010-09-14" on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-on-stack-overflow.