# my username has been changed from Nicolas78 to user151265

Tags: bug, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My profile just went blank?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64439/my-profile-just-went-blank)

What does that mean? Can I change it back?

Comment: correct. fixed, thx!