# My User ID has Changed

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My profile just went blank?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64439/my-profile-just-went-blank)

I've just had this experience:

I have been logging onto SO for over a year as dpbradley.  Today I noticed that my Id has changed to user62608, but everything else about my account stayed the same.

Two questions:

Is this a bug or some sort of pilot error I inadvertently made with Open ID?

How do I reverse this?

Thanks.