# what is the source of the random user ID's (userxxxx)?

Tags: support, user-accounts, display-names

They all seem to have exactly 1 point associated to their accounts.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/users/536443/user536443

[image]

They ask only a single question, never seem to accept an answer.

I suppose these are throwaways; are they being auto-generated by something or someone?

Comment: Related behavior: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64439/my-profile-just-went-blank/64542#64542

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the users do not choose a nickname (the Display Name which appears in edit profile page), their nickname will default to userxxxxxx where xxxxxx is the successive unique user ID number as is been assigned in the users table of the database.

As to the reputation, everyone get 1 rep to start with. It will stick to 1 rep if they do not ever accept answers or ever get upvoted. They can be downvoted, but the rep won't go lower than 1.

Comment: So no one ever get to the 0 or minus reputation That's good

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but they're probably just users looking for the solution to a single problem who don't realize they can ask without registering. They make an account, ask their question, get an answer, and leave immediately and forever

Comment: And if they *do* come back, they've forgotten what they used to log in with.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm asking