# What are all those user12345678 users?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, abuse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the source of the random user ID's (userxxxx)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71779/what-is-the-source-of-the-random-user-ids-userxxxx)

There are many users with name like user1234567 on SO, with 1 point and no history.
It appears like some automated Q&A system abusing SO. Or...? Thx

Comment: Damn that SO system, flooding the SO system with userxxxxs

Answer (score 2):

No those are the users who do not provide some custom names at the creation of account they just create the account in hurry so the user+some arbitrary number is assigned to the user as user name

Comment: Hmm... but there's so many. It didn't use to be so. Now it's every third.

Comment: Could it be confirmation bias that you are just now started paying attention to them? Can you substantiate it with some numbers for instance (don't know if that's easy to do, but still..).

Comment: Or it could be that the traffic and userbase is simply increased a lot