# How to reset a stackoverflow.com account that has been stranded

Tags: support, stack-overflow, login

For some reason my account on the main Stack Overflow website seems to have reverted to becoming `user{number}` with all my profile data (**INCLUDING OpenID information**) wiped out. The thing is I cannot reset the account anymore nor rename the account, login, or perform any actions.

It definitely is related to [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64433/username-missing-from-launchpad-openid-replaced-with-usernumber/64434), but I cannot reset the account anymore. When I try to login using my OpenID, I get asked to create a new account. I do not want to do this, and I would like to keep my existing reputation and questions.

No e-mail was set, so I can't use the "send info to email" link.

Comment: There was a downtime yesterday and 4h of data was lost (according to another meta post).

Comment: It appears there may be some complications due to the downtime and data loss that occurred recently. Like I did, I recommend reaching out to Stack Overflow support directly. They should be able to assist you in recovering your account and retaining your existing reputation and questions.

Answer (score 2):

For any oddball cases like this, you can't go wrong with e-mailing `team@stackoverflow.com`. You hardly even need to write anything beyond a pointer to this question.