# Why do some users have username "user########"?

Tags: discussion, display-names

Maybe I'm just missing something obvious, but what's up with this syntax? Is it because people sign up with e-mail addresses and use those for logging in, but don't bother giving themselves custom names (or completing their profile in any way)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This syntax is used for users who do not give themselves a name, as you said.

Previously, it was in the format *unknown(openIdProvider)*, and due to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35839/change-default-username-from-unknown-to-usernumber), it was determined that that format made it difficult to address those users in comments and answers (you could have several distinct users with *unknown(google)* as their name).

Comment: I figured that's what it was, but wanted to make sure. Just weird seeing people with 1000+ rep who haven't bothered to ID themselves in the community.

Comment: Also, the new global authentication caused users that used their openID username to be renamed the same way. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64433/146482) and [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64439/146482)