# Why have I started seeing a lot of usernames like 'user234878' on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some users have username “user########”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68053/why-do-some-users-have-username-user)

Why have I started seeing a lot of usernames like 'user234878' on Stack Overflow?

This makes me wonder if they are real people. Is it possible that these usernames are a product of the signup process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Exchange engine doesn't require registration to post questions or answers. You can log out and [try yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).
Thus, until user logs in and sets up a nickname, one has to be generated.

Comment: The clear down side to not registering or associating an OpenID is that if you flush cookies, you've lost your account. +1.

Comment: ah thanks. somehow i didn't realise that people could ask Qs without signup !

Comment: @tim you can get your cookie back as long as you gave us a valid email address and use the "recover login" option on the users/login page

Comment: @Jeff - Thanks, I did not realize that was possible.