# Is there a way to change the OpenID I use on all my accounts at once?

Tags: support, status-completed, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Copy Profile From Stack Overflow” didn't copy alternate OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/copy-profile-from-stack-overflow-didnt-copy-alternate-openid)

In a few hours, I will deactivate what has been my OpenID on all Stack Exchange sites. Is there a way to copy a new OpenID to all my accounts, or do I have to do it manually? I tried using the "Copy Profile To Related Accounts" feature, but it doesn't seem to copy the OpenID.

Comment: The copy my profile function should copy the *main* OpenID profile, but will not copy the alternate OpenID.  Are you sure that the main OpenID is not being copied?

Comment: @Adam Just tried it again and it didn't work.

Comment: @adam this is now possible, see my edit

Comment: @jeff hurray for freakish examples like us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's now a "Copy {Site} login credentials to all Stack Exchange accounts" button on the **account tab** of your user page now:

[image]

Comment: @adam outside of freakish examples like us, it is exceedingly rare for users to have accounts on more than a few sites.

Comment: True, true.

Comment: I'll admit I'm a bit of a special case - there was a time when I was creating an account on every single site that was created. (Looks like I'm up to 49)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously Jeff is right, but if you're going through and fixing them all anyway and you have a domain you control, you might want to make it an [OpenID delegate](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html#delegating_authentication) and use that. Then if you ever need to change the backing OpenID provider again, you just change where your domain points and it works automatically

Comment: For some providers, according to [I Can't Log In With My OpenID — Troubleshooting Tips](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips/63119#63119), one might need some more HTML than the 2 lines shown in the 1.1 specs linked above. See also [the 2.0 specs](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#anchor50), but these still do not mention the `<meta>` tag that myOpenID apparently needs too.