# Streamlining OpenID management for users across the Stack Exchange network

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there a way to change the OpenID I use on all my accounts at once?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89902/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-openid-i-use-on-all-my-accounts-at-once)

Back in 2009 Jeff answered this question:

> [“Copy Profile From Stack Overflow” didn't copy alternate OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/copy-profile-from-stack-overflow-didnt-copy-alternate-openid)

> We don't copy OpenIDs -- just the
> "soft" profile fields (pretty much
> everything else).

Is this still going to be the current stance? I'm switching my main OpenID login over to [the shiny new Stack Exchange OpenID provider](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/) and dropping my current primary to the alt provider. But with accounts on 22 of the Stack Exchange network sites there's a fair bit of faffing about.

Are there any plans to streamline OpenID management for users across the network?

**Update:**

You can now copy your login credentials to all your other SE accounts:

> [Since Googlemail has become Gmail my openIDs don't seem to match up.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93506/since-googlemail-has-become-gmail-my-openids-dont-seem-to-match-up/93627#93627)

Comment: Keep in mind, account association isn't *strictly* OpenID. Some measure of email sharing also lets you keep associations, [as shown in this answer by Jeff](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/how-do-stackexchange-sites-know-that-two-usernames-correspond-to-the-same-person/2249#2249). Doesn't address the matter of still needing to copy OpenID, but it does mean that you could switch OpenIDs on future accounts yet maintain association benefits.

Comment: Given that the SE OpenID has probably been in the pipeline for some time and based on the more recent answer by Jeff (which I missed), I'm going to close as dupe. I guess this probably won't happen. I think I'll spend the time creating a delegate instead.

Comment: completed, see linked duplicate