# Since Googlemail has become Gmail my openIDs don't seem to match up

Tags: support, openid, google-openid

I was wondering if this is something I am going to have to live with or is there a way to force gmail to think it is googlemail for the sake of my other openID accounts?

At the moment any new account I link to my google account will go in as gmail and is seen as a different user to my googlemail account.

**Edit for clarity**

I can log in with both @gmail and @googlemail, that isn't the issue.  The issue is that on the SE side they appear to be treated as different openID accounts and therefore on sites like Meta I can't associate myself with my account on SO, this is because with meta gmail was picked up as my openID and on SO googlemail was used.

I don't seem to have any control over if it picks up googlemail or gmail.  I guess the solution might be to add gmail to them all as this seems to be the new one, but if there is an easier way I would prefer it!

Comment: Flag one of your questions or answers and request a merge, specify both accounts and be specific regarding the OpenID you want to use.

Comment: Cheers, I have done this!

Answer (score 5):

This is not fixable at the moment; you'd need to log in to every other account with your "new" old credentials to get them mapped.

We are working on a "push my credentials out to every site on the network" feature but it's not quite there as of the time I am writing this.

---

There's a "Copy {Site} login credentials to all Stack Exchange accounts" button on account tabs now.
[image]