# Copy Profile to Related Accounts option should warn that it does not copy associated OpenIDs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, openid, usability, profile-copying

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Copy Profile From Stack Overflow” didn't copy alternate OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/copy-profile-from-stack-overflow-didnt-copy-alternate-openid)

Per ["Copy Profile From Stack Overflow" didn't copy alternate OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/copy-profile-from-stack-overflow-didnt-copy-alternate-openid), it is by design that all OpenID changes must be done individually for each site account, meaning that less-used accounts may not have a working OpenID even if the user updates the associations for more-used accounts.

Please make this clear in the warning shown when a user tries to copy his/her profile, possibly with the misconception that updating OpenID associations is part of it.