# Google Apps and DotNetOpenAuth 3.4

Tags: feature-request, openid, dotnetopenauth

I have read the [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12334/how-to-log-in-to-so-using-a-google-apps-account) about using Google Apps to login to stackoverflow, etc.   It seems there is a problem with the release of DotNetOpenAuth in use right now.  I see the release of [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.ohloh.net/p/dotnetopenauth) 3.4 is supposed to have [better support for Google Apps](http://groups.google.com/group/dotnetopenid/msg/dcec52038450e8f7), and it is now available.  Will the various stack properties be using version 3.4 soon?

Answer (score 1):

<s>We don't use DotNetOpenAuth, we use the older DotNetOpenID.</s>

We may switch at some point, but we had some stability concerns -- we're by far the largest consumer of that library, and we want it to be WELL tested before updating.

We now use DotNetOpenAuth, so if the library supports it, we should too.