# Is it possible to logon to StackOverflow using a google apps account?

Tags: support, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to log in to SO using a Google Apps account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12334/how-to-log-in-to-so-using-a-google-apps-account)

Is it possible to logon to StackOverflow using a google apps account?

On the logon page for stackoverflow, I put in https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=example.com for the OpenID URL.  The browser takes me over to google apps to login. I login successfully, but when the browser returns to stackoverflow, the stackoverflow page gives me an error:

> The OpenId Provider issued an
>   assertion for an Identifier whose
>   discovery information did not match.
>   Assertion endpoint info:
>   ClaimedIdentifier:
>   ht tp://example.com/openid?id=123445671234567712345
>   ProviderLocalIdentifier:
>   ht tp://example.com/openid?id=123445671234567712345
>   ProviderEndpoint:
>   ht tps://www.google.com/a/example.com/o8/ud?be=o8
>   OpenID version: 2.0 Service Type URIs:
>   (unavailable) Discovered endpoint
>   info: {}

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any problems using a Google Apps account with Stack Overflow. I simply click the big Google logo on the SO login page to login.