# Unable to login with google apps openid

Tags: support, google-openid

I'm aware that this question has been asked previously, even repeatedly, but I find no clear answer in either of the posts I can dig up. These, for example:
[How to log in to SO using a Google Apps account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12334/how-to-log-in-to-so-using-a-google-apps-account)
[How do you delegate your OpenId to Google Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436829/how-do-you-delegate-your-openid-to-google-apps/1204525#1204525)

Now, to the real question. When I click login, I get a big google logo as a choice. I click it and get to a standard google login page. Logging in here with my domain name however fails.

So in the second of the above posts I find this link:
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=your-domain.com
which I modify for my domain, obviously. Entering that adress into the "manually enter your openid" or into the URL field both direct me back to SO with:
"Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response"
which is completely different from a random URL that returns:
"No OpenID endpoint found."

If there's a question somewhere which provides more details on this error, I apologize for not finding it, but I have spent around an hour on this, with lots of searching, and I feel really stuck.

Comment: Probably no help, but do you have a google profile (http://www.google.com/profiles)? Because you can use that for an openid too. The main advantage is that it's easier to remember, and less chance of mistyping.