# Google OpenID login problems

Tags: support, openid, login

How do I find out what the OpenID of my Google account is?

I'd like to log in to join the Stack Overflow community, but the OpenID process is very frustrating for me. I did manage to log in a few weeks ago and I thought I managed to connect to my Google OpenID. But I don't recall the OpenID. The obvious option (my account username) is an email which can't be an OpenID. I can't find any reference to an OpenID when I look through the preferences, etc in my Google account. The OpenID.net site says to get my ID just go to Google and log in (no further hints given).

The whole point of OpenID is that it is simple to use but for me it is the exact opposite. Could Stack Overflow consider an old-fashioned username/password option? Or am I missing something really obvious?

P.S.: The login page has no way to register except by entering an OpenID.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips

Answer (score 6):

OK, finally found the answer - all I needed was to paste https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id into the login field.

What was happening was that noscript was blocking a third-party site javascript that shows a google icon and populates the link into the login field. That explains why nobody else was reporting this problem - you all have allowed that site (I think either sstatic.com or quantserve.com).

Comment: It was sstatic.com.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I find out what my google
>   account openid is?

Click the google picture at the login page and you'll automatically be redirected to the right place.

> Sorry, I know this should be posted in meta but I can't post there without logging in...

You don't need to login to read other posts, and there are lots of questions that already cover this [topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openid).

Answer (score 1):

'Click the google picture at the login page and you'll automatically be redirected to the right place.'
This directs me to the google account login page. Once I log in the link directs me to www.google.com.au. I suppose somewhere my account (https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageAccount) there is something I can do to find the openid, and maybe I'm stupid for not finding it, but I can't find it and would appreciate any suggestions on where to look.

'You don't need to login to read other posts, and there are lots of questions that already cover this topic.'
Sorry if my post sounded like it was from someone who had not tried to help themselves. I've read dozens of posts with the openid tag and spent about half an hour doing google searches and not found an answer to my question. Its a classic situation where the answer is probably so obvious that its incredibly hard to search for and nobody writes down the answer because they can see it so easily. In my opinion that is a really valuable role of a site like this where I can ask the question after I have got stuck. The reason I'd like to join serverfault is that the majority of the answers I've seen are helpful rather than condescending and there seem to be few flamewars which other sites I use are plagued with. I do have some skills and I'd like to also contribute answers.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't see the Google Logo as well, so my first experiance with the login process was very frustrating.