# Unable to log into SO with Google OpenID account

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, openid, login

I am getting this error when I try to log into Stack Overflow with a Google OpenID account:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> Positive assertion sent with OpenID version 1.1 but Identifier discovery suggested it would be 2.0

My OpenID URL is `http://openid-provider.appspot.com/santosh1984naidu`.

I am [san](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118682/san) on Stack Overflow.

I also tried using `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` with me being logged into the 
Google OpenID account in the next tab in the same browser, but I got the same error.

I have earned a good reputation on SO, and I don't want to start all over again.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22717/google-openid-login-problems

Comment: meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/22717/ I saw this but its of no use for me

Answer (score 2):

That is an unofficial google openid provider -- it is *not* from Google. I strongly urge you not to use that provider. Use the real GMail openid provider!

Comment: And to change your password...

Comment: it's not nefarious, it's just obsolete in the face of official support

Comment: It does re-raise an old issue though: how to disassociate an openid. Say it *was* suspected as nefarious - there is currently (AFAIK) no way to remove the alt openid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why openid has barfed, but... OK; how about this:

- create a new registered account with a different openid - perhaps your gmail
- use the same e-mail address (to make it easy to track)
- let me (or another mod here) know the new user id; we'll check the e-mail etc
- we'll merge the two accounts, leaving both openids on it

That work? (I'm e-mailing too; to prove ownership, an "ack" via e-mail would go a long way)

(I can't just copy your MSO gmail openid, as it is site-specific)

Comment: I cant put the same emailId its giving error "Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:

    * Email is already registered"

Comment: (sorry, my mistake with the e-mail, but since we've spoken over e-mail I think we can confirm it is you; try now)