# Having problems with my OpenID

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid, google

I inscribed myself just after dinner with OpenID: http://openid-provider.appspot.com/ thinking it was the right way to authenticate a OpenID account, unfortunately now I created an account there and I can't login any more :(

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
Positive assertion sent with OpenID version 1.1 but Identifier discovery suggested would be 2.0.
```

How can I get back to my old account? :(

Answer (score 1):

Use the email address at the bottom of every page.

edit: you should also know that you're using a completely unsanctioned OpenID provider that has no affiliation with Google. Really, *really* not recommended. To use the real, official Google OpenID click the giant Google logo on the [login page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login)

Comment: There you have it, you won't get any more "horse's mouth" than Jeff himself :-)

Comment: That's true! i realized too late :(, its the firt time i use openID, in fact now i'm writing from google... all i want to know is how to add my email, as it says "already in use" due to the appengine openid :(
anyone suggestions?

PS: Happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

I tried. This is pretty weird :(

I found this guy that had same problem as me:
[Unable to log into SO with Google OpenID account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29228/unable-to-login-with-google-openid-account-in-stackoverflow)

Comment: Just a gentle reminder. This should be added as a comment or updated into your own question post.

Comment: sry :D
has anyone got any clue? i can't even associate my email with the new account because stuck with the other:(

Answer (score 0):

It should now all be sorted; the only problem is that I think I broke the association between your SO and MSO accounts, but it is easy to re-associate - or wait a little while (until you have 200 points), and get the [free bonus](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/).