# Signing in with Yahoo OpenID fails on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, jobs, openid

My Yahoo OpenID works fine for the rest of the trilogy, but when I try to sign in to careers, it hangs.  It goes out to Yahoo's site but never comes back to the careers site.

Anything different in the authentication on that subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried logging in using a yahoo account and it worked.  Try a simple solution first - clear all of your browser cookies and try again.

Answer (score 1):

See:

[Can't log in with my OpenID - Troubleshooting Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips)