# Any Known Issues With OpenID and Weave

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, mozilla-weave

I have an account (which I created on another computer using weave). I'd like to log into that account from this computer, but I get an error message:

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

OpenID parameter 
'.....'
was expected to be base64 encoded but is not.
```

I'm using mac OS X 10.6.1, Firefox 3.5.3, Weave 0.7.

<strike>Is there a known issue with Weave?</strike>

OpenID functionality was removed from weave. See:
http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla-labs-weave/browse_thread/thread/18c97796e02e4f78
Please remove the option from the login screen. Thanks!

Comment: I managed to add my google login to SO, SU and SF via a third machine, but the machine was logged in from earlier. Unfortunately, it was not logged in to meta, so no luck there.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips

Comment: The test page referenced on this question (@John Smithers) also shows an error: Provide an OpenID first.
Invalid OpenID URL.
Login failed: Message parameter 'openid.mode' had unexpected value 'cancelhttp://test-id.org/OP/Sreg.aspx?OpenIdTextBox_UsePersistentCookie=False,id_res'.

Comment: Looks like Weave only supports `dumb` mode at the moment (whatever that is)http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla-labs-weave/browse_thread/thread/91c029840493645e - I assume SOFU expects a different one: 'openid.mode' had unexpected value - Conclusion: email the team!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is an issue with Weave.

Comment: What confuses me is that it had worked about a month ago. Well, I guess I'll have to live with not being able to use my "real" identity here, and look up how to merge them or delete this one later. Thanks!

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla-labs-weave/browse_thread/thread/18c97796e02e4f78 - openid functionality was removed from weave until after the 1.0 release.

Comment: Weave Login is now no longer an option on the login page. The status could be changed to status-completed if anyone cares :)