# Can't Log Into Stackoverflow With OpenID; Success With Meta

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t login to SO with openid - The signature verification failed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32247/cant-login-to-so-with-openid-the-signature-verification-failed)

OpenID has worked beautifully for me for a long time, but it's failing me today.

I cleared history in my Chrome browser today.  When I tried to log into Stackoverflow with my OpenID it failed.  I tried two other browsers, Firefox and IE, with the same result.  I get this message:

> "Unable to log in with your OpenID
>   provider:  The signature verification
>   failed."

I went to OpenID and reset my password.  It gets me back into Meta with no problem, but when I try again with Stackoverflow.com I get the signature verification failure message again.

I managed to get into Meta with enough success to ask this question, so I believe the account is valid.

I just successfully logged in using my Google ID, but then I'm asked to create a new account.  I'd rather not.

Why am I suddenly unable to log into Stackoverflow.com?

And please don't tell me how *you* can log out and back in again.  I have no doubt that you can, because I've been able to without any issues for over a year.

Comment: "Failed" in what way? I can't repro this; I just logged out and back in successfully.

Comment: When you get your account back you might want to add an alternate OpenID. Both points are less likely to be glitched at the same time.

Comment: Re your edit: I wasn't telling *you* "how *I* can log out and back in again"; I was 1. asking for more information and 2. trying to reproduce your issue and noting that I couldn't. Both of these might be interesting for people wanting to be of assistance. It's called "trying to be helpful"; sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Also: If you create that new account using Google ID, you can later mail team@stackoverflow.com to combine the accounts when it's back to working. Doesn't solve your problem, but would be a workaround for now.

Comment: I am also having problems with the system, getting 404 errors saying "Page Not Found" when I try to log in to my main account.