# Is there a problem with openid login on careers?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, openid

I'm using myopenid.com. It worked perfectly on all of SO websites, but now i can't login into carrers.

I'm getting:
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

The signature verification failed.

I tried so far:

1. clear cookies
2. different browser (Firefox and Chrome)
3. different website (stackoverflow.com works, careers.stackoverflow.com does not work)

OpenId provider logs show:

Approve for http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the problem.  I logged out of careers, then logged in with my personal openid (phpmyid hosted on my domain) and it was fine.

Vista, Firefox 3.5.8, phpmyid 0.9.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same OpenID you're using now?

also, see:

[Can't login to SO with openid - The signature verification failed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32247/cant-login-to-so-with-openid-the-signature-verification-failed)