# How do I get OpenID to work?

Tags: support, openid

I noticed that the [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/02/about-me.html) site now requires logging in with [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID). Well, I tried, but it gave an error message:

> The OpenID URL you provided is invalid.

I checked, and I wrote the URL just like it has been. What is wrong?

I signed out from Stack Overflow and tadaa, I cannot log back in. This gets to my nerves. I have to remember some kind of URL format instead of just a name. The whole thing is complex enough without hassle with URLs.

Comment: did your provider go down perhaps?

Comment: Check these steps: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips

Comment: Heh... Sounds like you need an easier-to-remember URL...

Comment: Oh so there is a provider and it can go down? And then there are 7 steps to try? Sounds complicated... I guess I need to try to get a new provider or try the steps. But not today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who is your OpenID provider?

Generally you just click the logo button of your provider on the login page; you don't have to remember URLs.

We've also improved the login page to make it more clear that there are buttons to click, see bottom part of screenshot below.

---

[image]