# Can't login with OpenID

Tags: support, openid, login

I am locked out of all my OpenID accounts. I can set new passwords via email, but I've failed to login multiple times.

When I try to login I get:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.
>   Do you already have an account on one of these sites? Click the logo
>   to log in with it here:

Comment: Perhaps you could try the "contact us" link at the bottom of this page.

Comment: "all my OpenID accounts" - I can only see one...?

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43705/138432) some time ago, so some of the advice there might be of use.

Basically, I was using google for my OpenID provider and in the end I used the [OpenId diagnostic](http://test-id.org/OP/Sreg.aspx) page to fix it for me, but I might have been able to get away with just clearing my google cookies.