# Cannot login with yahoo user name since more than two months

Tags: support, openid

Hello,
I am not able to login to SO for over 2 months now. I know there have been others here who have had the problem intermittently but for me it happens every time.
when I complete my login on the yahoo page, I get a drop down with two entries, one with my user name and one has some randon long text with the text '(last used)' appeneded to either of the entries (depending on which one I selected last). However, none of them allows me to access SO. After a some time I get the message 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage'

Can anyone help please.

Edit: I was able to just create a new account (for posting this question) on meta with the same yahoo user name and got a message that I already have an account on other sites and that my new account will be linked to them.

Comment: I think I know what your real problem is - "After a some time I get the message 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage'"

Comment: Well, with Chrome, I get the message "The webpage at http://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate/?s.... might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

And in the additional details link I get Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unknown error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the OpenID troubleshooting.

[Can't log in with my OpenID - Troubleshooting Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips)

Sounds like a proxy between you and us is blocking you.

Comment: I thought that our network admins at work had blocked this access (though they do not have a reason to). So, I did try to login from home and had the same issue. I use a comcast cable internet. 

However, I tried it this last week again from home and it works now. I can also connect from my work now.

Though I do not know what changed, I am glad it did.

Thanks for your response.