# I can't create an account

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, login

I'm having some trouble creating an account on Stack Exchange. I'm not using a proxy or anything weird to connect, but when I try to click, "Log In" on stackexchange.com, then click, "Log In With MyOpenID", which I have used for many services, and it asks me if I want to create a new account with this ID, I get directed to https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/openidconfirm, and I can't log in or do anything from there. If anyone could provide any troubleshooting tips it would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I also tried logging in with my Gmail account, which worked perfectly fine on Stack Overflow, but still no luck, I get the same error page.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed now.