# Can't login to Stack Overflow: "No account with this email found"

Tags: discussion, login, stack-overflow

I'm facing a problem with log in on Stack Overflow. My account (my email address) is not recognized anymore.

My username is jmcollin92, I'm sure what email address I used before, but the log in on Stack Exchange always tells me "No account with this email found".

Any clues (I would like to get my account back ...) and not restart from scratch.

The only think different is that I've change my PC. I can't trys anymore with the old one.
I read this but without success : [Can't log in with my OpenID - Troubleshooting Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips)

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Arrrgh. You're right. I go there.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1616656/jmcollin92) user?